# remove string using sed that include slash

Tags: bash, sed, slash

Here is the data I have:

```
This is a test/><STUFF
This is a test/><TRY
```

I am trying to be rid of `/><STUFF` and `/><TRY` in bash using `sed`.

So as result having the two sentences.

```
This is a test
This is a test
```

Comment: is the text always like this? Do you always want to remove from the first slash? Clarify it not to get answers relying on this if it is not the case.

Comment: Looks like you're actually working with some HTML/XML here...

Comment: @TomFenech, not necessarily. Such data may be the output of grepping through a HTML file, so working with regexes is not a bad idea. Whether HTML file should be grepped in the first place is another matter — I guess it depends on the file itself and on what is to be achieved.

Comment: is is always one of those 2 word that end or something else could occurs (and other than word, especially the `/` occuring twince in a line) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove everything from the slash:

```
$ sed 's_/.*__' file
This is a test
This is a test
```

Note the usage of `_` as delimiter, since the typical slash `sed 's/find/replace/' file` collides with the pattern you are looking for. You can also escape it.

Or with `cut`, set the delimiter as a slash and just print the first field:

```
$ cut -d'/' -f1 file
This is a test
This is a test
```

Although the cleanest is `awk`:

```
$ awk -F/ '{print $1}' file
This is a test
This is a test
```

A bash solution is:

```
while IFS="/" read name _
do
   echo "$name"
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this,

```
sed 's~/.*~~' file
```